# MEF - How do I create a new ViewModel (or reset its state) if I'm using MEF? Also, how do I avoid memory issues?

Tags: c#, wpf, mef, memory-management

Basically, I'm worried about a couple of things:

```
[Export]
public class FooViewModel : NotificationObject
{
    [Import]
    public IService1 Service1 { get; set; }

    [Import]
    public IService2 Service2 { get; set; }

    [Import]
    public BarViewModel MyBar { get; set; }

    etc.

    //This is already initialized
    public ObservableCollection<NotificationObject> CollectionOfViewModels { get; set; }

    public void SetupViewModels1()
    {
        CollectionOfViewModels.Clear();
        CollectionOfViewModels.Add(MyBar);
        CollectionOfViewModels.Add(MyOtherBar);
        CollectionOfViewModels.Add(My3rdViewModel);
        etc.
    }

    public void SetupViewModels2()
    {
        CollectionOfViewModels.Clear();
        CollectionOfViewModels.Add(MyBar);
        CollectionOfViewModels.Add(My4thViewModel);
        etc.
    }
}

[Export]
public class BarViewModel : NotificationObject
{
    [Import]
    public IService1 Service1 { get; set; }

    [Import]
    public IService2 Service2 { get; set; }

    //This is initialized and then the user starts adding values to it.
    public ObservableCollection<Object> SomeObjects { get; set; }

    public void DoSomething() { ... }
}
```

(1) Issue #1, I load my FooViewModel and everything is nice and dandy. I choose to load my first set of ViewModels to do some work with them. Then when I go to load my second set of ViewModels BarViewModel is still the same instance (so all of it's properties are the same, including the `SomeObjects` property. How do you tell it to reinitialize itself so all of it's data is cleared? If, instead I do `MyBar = new MyBar()` then MyBar doesn't initialize `IService1` or `IService2` (because MEF didn't initialize it, I did).

(2) Issue #2, When I'm not using my other ViewModels they still reside in memory because I imported them with MEF, which means their states are all there as well, which means large large collections are sitting eating away at my memory. How do you fully get rid of a ViewModel when you aren't using it anymore?

See, before I was using MEF I would do the following:

```
CollectionOfViewModels.Clear();
CollectionOfViewModels.Add(new MyBar());
etc.
```

This would mean when I do my next set of ViewModels as soon as I did `CollectionOfViewModels.Clear();` any of the ViewModels that were in the collection are no longer being referenced and the GC collects them. As it stands right now, doing this doesn't actually get rid of any of the ViewModels.

Comment: For Issue #1: [PartCreationPolicy (CreationPolicy.NonShared)]

Comment: @Derek: But I only have one reference to it, I just want to "reset" it so it's as if I did `MyBar = new MyBar();` I don't want to have to make 2 separate imports and have 2 properties one for each time I'm going to use it.

Comment: I see, I'm curious as to what the collections are for or what the View is like for FooViewModel.  You might want to look at Caliburn Micro's screens and conductors.  They help with VM/screen lifetime management and things like a child screen telling a parent to close it. http://goo.gl/cFYHi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you familiar with MEF's `ExportFactory` functionality?  It allows you to create a new instance of an export, as well as release it when you are done with it.  That sounds like what you want to do here.

Comment: It's only available in Silverlight. I guess I should of been specific to state that I'm working with WPF.

Comment: @michael The next version of MEF for desktop will have ExportFactory, and a preview of that is available at http://mef.codeplex.com.  For the codeplex release the assembly identity is different, so it won't work with parts compiled against the .NET 4 version of MEF- you have to compile everything against te codeplex version.

Comment: Also, Glenn Block has created a standalone dll to add that functionality in. Though, I did always wonder what's to stop someone from manually adding the dll targeted at Silverlight that's part of .NET 4? http://cid-f8b2fd72406fb218.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/blog/Composition.Initialization.Desktop.zip

Comment: Hmm, I like the idea of the standalone dll a bit better than replacing all of MEF.